# Confirm before deleting data in database passing variable through onclick

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, confirm

```
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'"><img src="img/delete.png" width=20px height=20px name="delete"></a></td></tr>';
```

this is my img icon. whenever you click it, it will navigate you to a new page where the deletion happens.

```
echo "<script>window.confirm('Delete?')</script>";

$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "UPDATE `main` SET status=0 where id = $id";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
if ($sql->execute()) {
    echo "<script>
            window.location='view.php';
        </script>";
}
?>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/dist/js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is delete.php. but i need to check first if the window.confirm is true before doing the deletion. but i don't know how

Answer (score 1):

Instead put the `confirm()` in the link of image before navigating to another page

```
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Delete?\')"><img src="img/delete.png" width=20px height=20px name="delete"></a></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
    <?php { ?>
        <a href="deleteme" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: where does that "deleteme" navigate you? i tried it but it gives out an error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'onclick=' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\delete.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\delete.php(20): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\delete.php on line 20